# IE: How to handle cross-domain cookies?

Tags: php, iframe, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, session-cookies

My main Site (*hostsite*) has an `IFRAME` with a registration site (*regsite*) hosted on a different domain.

I want to host the registration on a different domain, because I feel storing the DB login information on *hostsite* is not safe as many people have access to the backend.

All browsers accept the login session-cookie coming from *regsite* - Internet Explorer 8 does not. The only way to make IE accept this cookie is by adding both sites to "Trusted Sites" which is not what i want.

Is there any way I can work around the cross-domain issue besides a local browser setting or is my only option to move the registration to *hostsite* (`curl` is not an option as it's not static HTML I'm displaying on the registration site, but PHP files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be solved without moving anything, and little programming. Just with some DNS rules.

For example, you can create a new subdomain called *register.hostsite(.com)* pointing to the ip where *regsite* is.

Then re-direct the `IFRAME` to that new subdomain.

It will get the same bits from the same server, but now it will be inside hostsite's domain.

That should (at least in theory) be enough to satisfy IE. I'm not 100% sure though, I haven't used IFRAMES in a long time.

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest asking on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), too.

EDIT: I was looking for another issue and found this 'micro-proxy' PHP implementation by yahoo. It's their recommended way of resolving this kind of issues:

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt

Comment: **subdomain: Very good idea!** I'm not a fan of `iframe`s either, but is there another option if you want to host a page from somewhere else inside your main site?

Comment: Cool idea. Was faced with the same issue when trying to iframe a third party payment gateway.

Comment: Unfortunately on shared hosting this is not the solution, because I can't hook the subdomain directly to a different domain - all my host is offering is HTTP-Redirects & Frame redirects...

Comment: that's unfortunate. There's probably a way of doing some kind of "bridge" on php (so it sends client requests to the registration site, and back). I'm not sure it would be worth the time. It depends on how much time would it take to implement registration on hostsite.

Comment: right now I'm thinking of just moving the registration to the host site... easier solution probably ;-)

Comment: hi again! I found a php implementation for making a proxy-ish thing on php. I'm adding it to my answer. It should allow you to redirect your contacts to hostsite/contact.php (no subdomains needed).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the iframe and IE is that IE considers the iframe's content as 3'rd party (as in advertisements etc).

To have IE actually store the cookies set by this domain document you need to have the other domain emit an [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)-header stating its intentions. This is easy to do and requires only a single http-header to be added.

I'm, not sure what you mean by cross domain issues though as there are none - you simply have two different documents from two different domains. You have not stated whether you are trying to have one domain set cookies for the other, or one page access the other.

Comment: Nup. two totally different domains, they don't need to interact. The one is simply a framework (main page) holding the registration page. Cross-Domain: IE just doesn't like the page in the IFRAME setting a cookie. It just isn't accepted in the "Internet Zone" Never heard of P3P, I'll look into it!