# Internet Explorer (only) breaks on iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

http://midcityeast.com/iframe.html is has an iframe pointing to midcityeast.crowdmap.com :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://midcityeast.crowdmap.com/" width="1000" height="1200" frameborder="0"              
       scrolling="yes" class="iframe-class"></iframe>
  </body>
 </html>
```

This works fine in most browsers, but yields a blank page and then a 503 error in MSIE on Vista and Windows 7 using MSIE 9.

Looking under the hood - F12 to track network activity - I see that MSIE requests https://midcityeast.crowdmap.com/ more than 400 times, each time getting a 200-ok response and a blank response body, for a 500 character or so response. After 400 or so of these requests, the server sends a 503, probably as a rate-limiting measure.

In comparison, MacOSX/Chrome requests midcityeast.crowdmap.com just twice, and gets what it needs. The page works fine in Chrome and Firefox on both Windows and Mac.

Is there a fix or workaround for this? We have folks on MSIE and can’t easily get them to use other browsers.

Comment: I don't have direct access to IE, but I'd take a look at what request and response headers when using IE. I'm thinking there's something triggering the site to think it needs to refresh (cookies not being sent because of cross domain?).

Comment: Yes. I've seen some references on SO about cookies not being sent/received on iframes for MSIE due to MSIE's more restrictive privacy policies - investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got access to IE, and I'm 99% confident it has to do with the restricted rules for cookies. When the first request goes into `midcityeast.crowdmap.com` the sersver sets a cookie `cmgatekeeper` with a value. Then a redirect happens which allows the content to be loaded.

[IE: How to handle cross-domain cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866306/ie-how-to-handle-cross-domain-cookies) has a little more information about it. They propose using a proxy which you host on your server which handles all the communication, but that could be challenging in a AJAX'ed web application.

You may want to ask the IT administrators to add an exception for the third party cookies. Or maybe use a service that allows embedding using a Javascript, or doesn't require a use of this cookie.

Comment: Definitely. Go to http://jsfiddle.net/VUff9/ in MSIE, wait about 1 minute, see a 503 error. Then, via MSIE->Options-> Privacy, set the policy slider to accept all cookies, and MSIE works.  I'll check into embedding via javascript.